# Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have developed Asp.Net Core 3.1 API and deployed on the server through IIS, it's working as expected if I send the GET/POST request from Postman or browser, But Below code is giving error.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'json',
   url: 'myUrl',
   success: function(jsondata){
   }
})
```

**Error:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://server:8080/API/GetMethod?currency=INR'
> from origin 'http://localhost:63765' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I have disabled the CORS from my application using the below code
**C# code:**

```
[DisableCors]
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class APIController : ControllerBase
{
```

startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

        

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

So I have tried disabling the CORS on controller level, I have tried `jsonp` also instead of `JSON`, It's still getting the same error.

I have two questions here.

1. Is this clientside or serverside issue?
2. How to fix the error?

**Note:** I able to send GET requests from browser and Postman, but with this clientside code, I am getting the CORS related issue.

Comment: I don’t think you want to disable CORS. The error cited in the question is caused by CORS being disabled. CORS is what would enable cross-origin requests to work as expected rather than failing with the error cited in the question.

Comment: @sideshowbarker so what's the solution?

Comment: I  have tried the solution provided by @atakan. But still getting the error

Comment: If postman works and your code doesn't, the problem is obviously in your code, see the request from postman, headers and body and everything, and then using console.logs see what you are sending, compare it. Sometimes, it is just a character, use some tools that give you the difference between texts if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was due to I was using `[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]` on the controller, but added `[DisableCors]` on the method. so it might be overwriting the CORS policy. So I removed `[DisableCors]` from the method and it started working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** It should be server side problem. Because server is blocking the origin who makes request.

**2.** I had similar problem before in feature. Instead of using `[DisableCors]` and `[AllowAnonymous]`, you can make some configuration in startup.cs

**details:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

`AllowAnyOrigin`: *Allows CORS requests from all origins with any scheme (http or https). AllowAnyOrigin is insecure because any website can make cross-origin requests to the app.*

recomended solution (if this not work you can maybe use AllowAnyOrigin):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                builder =>
                                {
                                    builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                        "http://www.contoso.com")
                                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                                });
        });

        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

Comment: Did you change origin ? "http://example.com" Plus you can try ".AllowAnyOrigin()"

Comment: I added `builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();`